# What is the best way to create AngularJS ACL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I want to share with you (community) my problem.

I use `MEAN` stack, so I use `Node.js` with `Express` and `AngularJS` and I have singe app application.

I use `passport` as an authentication strategy in `Node \ Express \ Jade` code.
I want to create admin section on my page to manage users and others stuff.

I want also protect this AngularJS sites loaded asynchronously by adding some access control to my $routeProvider like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/admin/users', {
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/users.html',
    auth: {
        required: true,
        roles: ['admin']
    }
})
```

This is only pseudocode which I want to achive in my real solution.
If user is not logged in, should be redirect to `/signin` page, and if user is logged in and does not have proper role to view this page, should be redirect to appropiate view with custom information.

Comment: Question is both, too broad and too opinionated.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to handle access control on the server side, and just not serve anything up to the user if s/he shouldn't be able to access it. Then I field and interpret the response from the server to do things like rerouting to a sign-in form.

This allows for really flexible security mechanisms. For example, I can configure my backend security with a firewall for something like you've described (where a route "/admin" and all of its descendants should be protected). I can use ACLs to secure individual objects, or a `SecurityManager` that allows for more complex analyses of the user making the request.

Maybe this isn't a direct answer to your question, but instead encouragement to approach the problem differently. Still I think it's a better approach than anything that I've seen in terms of pure JS access control.

Comment: I'll +1 if you include break-down of your setup, code snippets, etc ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at UI-Router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

It is pretty cool and you can intercept state changes based on whatever security scheme you want.

We are using it with a permission/role/group based security scheme and it works awesome.