# AngularJS ACL view level examples

Tags: angularjs, acl

It's clear how to organise ACL on client-router level to prevent access for some states, it's also pretty straight forward how to do it on the API side.

But what could you recommend to do with the View layer? We want to hide and show some widgets depending on permissions.
Should it be just ng-if? Like:

```
<widget ng-if="can('admin', 'mainWidget')"></widget>
```

or probably you would suggest more sophisticated solutions?

...

Related stackoverflow links:

[Bullet-Proof ACL using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793328/bullet-proof-acl-using-angularjs)

[What is the best way to create AngularJS ACL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926126/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-angularjs-acl)

Ready solution(but not to my taste):

https://github.com/mikemclin/angular-acl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declarative programming may be good for simple things but for application design this would be a step back. Using global ACL state/method (`can()`) on root scope forces the app to expose it to scope everywhere.

```
app.directive('acl', (auth) => ({
  scope: {
    aclRole: '@',
    aclRule: '@'
  },
  transclude: true,
  template: '<div ng-transclude ng-if="auth"></div>',
  link: (scope) => {
    scope.$watchCollection(['aclRole', 'aclRule'], () => {
      auth.can(scope.aclRole, scope.aclRule).then((can) => scope.auth = can);
    })
  }
}));
```

For synchronous ACL (in the case when it was already resolved in route resolver) `auth.can` can be changed to return a value rather than a promise.

And the usage is

```
<acl acl-role="admin" acl-rule="mainWidget">...</acl>
```

Comment: it looks like it's the only answer, so I'll mark it as right :)